# Select max price for each art

Tags: sql, select

I have to select max price for each article

I have that table:

```
create table shop (
article int(4) unsigned zerofill default '0000' not null,
dealer char(20) default '' not null,
price double(16,2) default '0.00' not null,
primary key (article, dealer));

insert into shop values(1, 'A', 3.45), (1,'B', 3.99),
(2, 'A', 10.99), (3, 'B', 1.45), (3, 'C', 1.69), 
(3, 'D', 1.25), (4, 'D', 19.95);
```

and tried to do this code:

```
select article, dealer, max(price) from shop group by article;
```

but it shows wrong dealers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCiU1.png)

price 3.99 is in dealer B, but it shows A

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from shop s
where s.price = (select max(s2.price) from shop s2 where s2.article = s.article);
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema and input statements:

```
 create table shop ( article int(4) unsigned zerofill default '0000' not null, dealer char(20) default '' not null, price double(16,2) default '0.00' not null, primary key (article, dealer));
 
 insert into shop values(1, 'A', 3.45), (1,'B', 3.99), (2, 'A', 10.99), (3, 'B', 1.45), (3, 'C', 1.69), (3, 'D', 1.25), (4, 'D', 19.95);
```

Query:

```
with cte as 
         (
             select article, dealer, price, max(price)over(partition by article)maxprice from shop
         )
         Select article,dealer,price from cte where price=maxprice;
```

Output:

```
 |article | dealer | price|
 |------: | :----- | ----:|
 |   0001 | B      |  3.99|
 |   0002 | A      | 10.99|
 |   0003 | C      |  1.69|
 |   0004 | D      | 19.95|
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1fc80cbf4c2b5cddc63728dbf63f4ba)*